# Using RestKit to map my objects

Tags: ios, json, restkit, restkit-0.20

I use JSON all the time in my apps

in my Android apps, i use Gson to deserialise JSON Objects that come from the server.

What i love about Gson, is that all i need to do is create an POJO class with the given attributes and they are mapped automatically with `Gson.fromJSON(JsonString, POJO.class);`

and if i want the objects to be named differently than what they arrive from the server, i just add an annotation @SerializedName("server'sName")`

Is there such a way to do that in `RestKit`?
it seems very tedious to name all the properties by hand ?
what if i add/remove/rename properties ?

currently this is my class

```
@interface Test 
@property (nonatomic,assign) int prop1;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *prop2;
@end
```

this is my JSON :

```
{ "prop1":10, "prop2":"test"}
```

this my mapping

```
   //map class component
    RKObjectMapping *statsMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Test class]];
    [statsMapping   addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"prop1":@"prop1",@"prop2":@"prop2"}];

    // Register our mappings with the provider using a response descriptor
    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:responseMapping
                                                                                            method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                                                                       pathPattern:nil
                                                                                           keyPath:nil
                                                                                       statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
    [objectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
```

what i would like is for `RestKit` to map to my properties (if they exist in both the `JSON`, and my class) without naming them by name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trim your mapping definition with:

```
[statsMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[ @"prop1", @"prop2" ]];
```

RestKit uses the mapping definitions to limit what is being processed and to allow the application of structure and flexibility into the mapping process.

It's possible that you could use `RKDynamicMapping` and `setObjectMappingForRepresentationBlock:` to analyse the incoming data in association with a known target class and use reflection to check that the destination variables exist...

Comment: do I need to do the reflection, or does RestKit does it ?

Comment: RestKit reflects on data type of the variables to determine what translations are required during mapping but it doesn't reflect on what variables exist to know what to map - it requires to be told what key names to map.

Comment: why didnt RestKit create a "default" mapping scheme, for which it relies on the names of the variables to map to, and if some variables are missing, they are left nil  or discarded depending where they are located (JSONvsClass) ?

Comment: A subclass of `RKObjectMapping` could be created which did that when instantiated with a target class. You could even implement it and raise a pull request to have it added to the framework. The google group would be a better place to discuss potential additions (as opposed to usage).

Comment: Actually after further inspection of the RestKit classes, there is a class that does that in the RestKit, so changing the library to do what i want is very easy to do -> so i created a method that converts the properties of the class into a string NSArray and put it into the addAttributeMappingsFromArray as you suggested, the whole thing took 5 minutes to do! too bad they didn't consider adding it